# React Router Kepps css when switching Routes

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

I have a problem With my code i am using react-router-dom@6 and have countered a problem i have made a `<Home />` `<Login />` `</Register />` Components and i am using react router to switch between them but for some reason when i switch for example from  to `<Login />` the background stays the same which i have defined in **Home.css** and only imported in `<Home />` but when i try to define background again in **Login.css** that becomes the default on all pages this has confused me for a long time now and i would like some advice on i how i should deal with it

**App.js**

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import Login from "./Components/Login";
import Register from "./Components/Register";

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="App">
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="/Login" element={<Login />} />
                    <Route path="/Register" element={<Register />} />
                </Routes>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import "../Css/Home.css";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Home() {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            <main>
                <h1>YelpCamp</h1>
                <p>Welcome To YelpCamp</p>
                <p>Jump In And Explore Our Campgrounds</p>
                <Link to="/Campgrounds">
                    <button className="button">View Our Campgrounds</button>
                </Link>
            </main>
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

**Home.css**

(Only the important CSS )

```
/*BODY*/

body {
    background: url("../Images/Home\ Background.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 90vh;
}
```

**Login.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import "../Css/Login.css";
function Login() {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            <main>Login Page</main>
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

**Login.css**

(Only the important CSS )

```
/*BODY*/

body {
    background: #000;
}
```

And the Same for **Register.js** and **Register.css** only changing the body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what happens is that you have basically defined 3 body queries in CSS, because by default css in react applies on whole app, not only on component, where is importad... what changes is just order based on which component was loaded first according to your route.

To achieve what you want, you can change body classes using `useEffect` in your routes

```
useEffect(() => {
 document.body.classList.add('register');
},[])
```

but its not clear way how to do it and i suggest to consider make your own `Layout` component, which wraps your whole app and change className based on your url (you can use `useRouteMatch` hook from react-router)

edit:
Or you can style `<div className='app'>` instead by adding some classes here

Comment: I will try that , Thanks ❤️

Comment: But just a stupid question what is the difference between useLocation and useRouteMatch

Comment: you can use useRouteMatch outside of <route> component... useLocation must be used in child of <route> :)

Comment: and would you suggest that i define the classes in App.css or in each .css file individually

Comment: I would suggest to define it in App.css, or you can have a look at some technologies for styling in react: Css modules, styled components...